# jQuery noconflict() breaks my jquery code..?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I am developing a joomla 2.5 component and I am using a lot of jQuery in my code.
I am using jQuery noconflict() to avoid any conflicts...
The problem is with a very simple show / hide jquery code for a div which is meant to enable the user to hide the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.slidingDiv').show();
    jQuery('.show_hide').show();

jQuery('.show_hide').click(function(){
jQuery('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
}); });
```

Whenever I include the jQuery noconflict() as follow:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery.noConflict()');
```

the above show / hide script does not work, but other jquery scripts on the same page are working fine!

The html implementation:

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
        <a href="#" class="show_hide"><img style="float:right;"src="/images/close.png" alt="hide"></a> text here </div>
```

and the css:

```
.slidingDiv {
height:85px;
background-color: #6A5C53;
padding:10px;
margin:4px auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 6px;
moz-border-radius:6px;
webkit-border-radius:6px;
width:920px;
z-index: 50;}


.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

any ideas anyone?? Any help would be very much appreciated! 
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with jquery in joomla backend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003613/problem-with-jquery-in-joomla-backend)

Comment: You realize you have a dollarsign in the document ready function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` should be `jQuery` in your document.ready function.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//^^^------here;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! can't believe I missed it... rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that use a self-invoking anonymous function so you can do something like this and not need the `jQuery.noConflict()` declaration:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slidingDiv').show();
    $('.show_hide').show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

See http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/ask-jw-decoding-self-invoking-anonymous-functions/ for more details.

Comment: Doesn't work for some reason, but it's Fixed so thank you anyway!